# Why is new PC hanging on boot?

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

I'm helping my son set up a new PC - we have an MSI B550 motherboard and Samsung 980 M.2 SSD. Windows 10 install went ok, but when I reboot the PC, it just hangs. I get the BIOS splash screen but it doesn't get any further. If I reset the CMOS, I can boot to the BIOS and check settings - the SSD drive tests ok and is detected as having Windows installed.

I've sent back the SSD and got a replacement, and also tried the other M2 slot on the motherboard. Neither of these things has made a difference.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Are these devices compatible?

Comment: Have you checked if there is a BIOS update available for your board?

Comment: To rule out hardware issues, boot from a live USB, e.g. Ubuntu. If that works, then the issue is with the HDD and/or OS installation. If you can't even boot from USB, there are likjely hardware or BIOS setting issues.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I booted to XUbuntu USB and it loaded fine. I could mount the Windows drive and check it for errors. Everything seemed to be OK.

Comment: @Robert I have now - upgraded from v1.50 to v1.81 but still the same issue. Should I return the motherboard?

Comment: Since XUbuntu runs, there's likely no problem with the motherboard, or anything else. **Double check BIOS settings**, and that the image on the SSD is actually *bootable*. Those are the most likely causes.

Comment: I tried actually installing XUbuntu on the SSD and it boots and reboots many times. No problems at all. So I reinstalled Windows on the SSD and it managed to reboot during install, but it hung again after the install was finished. I'll just tell him he has to run XUbuntu on it - pretty sure you can install Steam with Wine :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your help, but the solution turned out to be that you have to install [Samsung Magician](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/magician/) before you restart the PC.

It must contain drivers and other stuff that Windows needs to get it working. No idea why it isn't documented anywhere that the drive will not work without it.